# Search Algorithm in Java Collection

Tags: java, collections

This question might have been answered. I couldn't find it though.

In Java Collections i have always used Collections.sort(coll) followed by search. My question is that will collections always perform binary search or is it decided internally. Does collection store any identifier to decide between linear and binary search.

Comment: The search algorithm depends on the collection. What you're doing now is the worst possible solution. You should use ordered collections, or hashed ones.

Comment: If you mean you are using Collections.binarySearch, that only works on a lists that are sorted already -- the list does not keep track of this.  The results are undefined if you are using a list that is not sorted

Comment: @EJP In my opinion ordered collections will be time consuming for inserts. Instead i would use a unordered collections and sort it finally once my data set is loaded. Do you suggest otherwise?

Comment: @john16384 Does contains and indexof operations use binary search as well?

Comment: It depends on the collection.  For `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` both `indexOf` and `contains` are O(n), for `HashSet` `contains` is O(1).

Comment: Different data structures have different costs for inserting, removing, searching etc - the overall cost depends on how often you perform each of these operations. Whether or not the overhead of maintaining an ordered collection is a problem depends on how many times you insert, remove, search etc.

Comment: It is a bit of a gap in the Java collections available that there is no sorted tree or list (good insert performance) that also maintains an index -- such a thing is often needed for views that show a list, that can be sorted and can change (like a directory).

Comment: @sekar I *did* suggest otherwise. I suggested using 'ordered collections, or hashed ones'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at the Java 8 source code of `Collections.sort(coll)`, it uses the `Arrays.sort(Object[] a)` method. If you do not pass `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort` as a system property. Otherwise, it uses legacy merge sort.

`Arrays.sort(Object[] a)` uses TimSort which is strategic algorithm that chooses insertion sort or merge sort according to the given array's ordering and size. You can find the details in below links:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-
- https://hackernoon.com/timsort-the-fastest-sorting-algorithm-youve-never-heard-of-36b28417f399